# jQuery, HTML 5 and IE give wrong animation

Tags: jquery, html, animation

I have problem with jQuery animation in IE (I test it in IE 8). Site is written in HTML5 and I have figure tag with img tag inside.

On click I want to move all figure element, so in animate function I just give new left position. On FF, Opera and Chrome it works good, on IE is problem.

It looks like IE redraws HTML once on 200 ms. If I have animation with "slow", there are 3 jumps from start position to the end, with "fast there is only one jump...

Please help me.

Here is a simple code I use:

This is a function that creates figure:

`var createElement = function (w, h, left, id, photo, caption, HTMLclass) {`

`var nid = Math.round(Math.random()*100)*1000 + (id*1);`

`var figure = $("<figure>").css({"z-index":1,"width":w+"px","height":h+"px","left":left+"px","cursor":"pointer"}).attr("id",(nid+1)).attr("onclick","moveElements(this)").addClass(HTMLclass);`

`var img = $("<img>").attr("src","photo/co/" + photo).attr("alt", caption).css({"z-index":2,"width":w+"px","height":h+"px"});`

`var figcaption = $("<figcaption>").text(caption);
  $("body").append(figure.append(img).append(figcaption));`

`};`

And here is a loop with animate:

`var figures = $("figure").each(function(index) {
      $(this).animate({"left": newLeft}, "slow");
};`

Comment: Code? And does IE8 properly support HTML5?

Answer (score 0):

It may have to do with Internet Explorer not knowing what to do with newer HTML 5 tags. Try inserting the following Javascript into your head. What the javascript does is creates elements for article, footer, header, etc. so older browsers have those elements to work with from the DOM load.

```
document.createElement("article");  
document.createElement("footer");  
document.createElement("header");  
document.createElement("hgroup");  
document.createElement("nav");
document.createElement("feature");
```

If that doesn't work, try posting your code in here so we can look more closely. The cross browser issue seems to point to IE not knowing how to handle those elements though.

Comment: I use jquery to create and animate elements (it creates everything good, img not needs to be close in HTML5) and http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js to force IE to display all tags correctly. It works quite good. Only one thing, that not works as it should, is animate...